# Async/Await in Vue with mount() hook not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-promise

I'm using vue 2.5 and I have a mount hook that calls a module that fetches an API nedpoint and returns it to vue component via the mount hook. I have previously asked question and been referred to post [return response from async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and have followed examples in answer but still my Vue component variable shows as undefined when component rendered. Here is my code:

```
/modules/retrieveLeagueLeaders

 const getLeagueLeaders =  (url, params) => {
    fetch(url + new URLSearchParams(params), {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          "Basic ****=",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let leagueLeaders = data;
        console.log(
          "leagueLeaders is %s",
          leagueLeaders.cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry[0].player
            .LastName
        );

        return leagueLeaders;
        
      });

    
  };

  module.exports = getLeagueLeaders;
```

and the Vue code:

```
/src/components/leagueLeaders
 mounted: async function () {
      this.qbLeaders = await getLeagueLeaders(this.fetchQbUrl, this.params);
      console.log("qBLeaders is %s", this.qbLeaders);
    },
  })
```

Console shows

```
qBLeaders is undefined nflLeagueLeaders.js:28
leagueLeaders is Wilson getLeagueLeaders.js:17
```

I have tried wrapping whole module in a Promise but still it does not return a promise when run. Is there something to how I am using Async/Await in Vue mount hook that is incorrect? I could really use some guidance as I have tried all suggestions in posts to no avail. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your `getLeagueLeaders()` function does not return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to return a value inside a callback, this doesn't work, you could simply return the promise :

```
const getLeagueLeaders =  (url, params) => {
   return  fetch(url + new URLSearchParams(params), {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          "Basic ****=",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
         
  };

  module.exports = getLeagueLeaders;
```

Comment: Thanks! Short and precise. I had stumbled on a similar approach now but yours is even shorter and elegant. I thought you had to assign response.json() to something and then return that. So is the response.json() the implied resolve value of the Promise?

Comment: it's my pleasure